# Why do I get an error for swap when the two values are equal in Java?

Tags: java, swap

I am not sure why I get this error and do not know how to solve it. I am getting a Runtime Exception:

```
for(int j = 0; j < instances[maxInstance].length; j++){

                            centroids[orphanCentroid][j]=instances[maxInstance][j];

                       }

                           for(int j = 0; j < instances[maxInstance].length; j++){
                                {
                                double temp = centroids[maxInstance][j] ;
                                centroids[maxInstance][j] = centroids[orphanCentroid][j] ;
                                centroids[orphanCentroid][j] = temp ;

                           }
```

Error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at kmeans.KMeans.cluster(KMeans.java:75)
    at kmeans.HW1.main(HW1.java:36)
```

And it happens at this line:

```
  double temp = centroids[maxInstance][j] ;
```

Comment: Are `centroids[maxInstance]` and `instances[maxInstance]` the same length?

Comment: Is that extra curly bracket a typo after the second `for loop` in your question? Or do you have an anonymous block?

Comment: @hexafraction yeah the problem is with that!

Comment: I guess this could only happen if `centroids[maxInstance]` is shorter than `instances[maxInstance]`.  So perhaps you could post the code where those two arrays are actually set.  The problem is not in the snippet that you posted.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need

```
for(int j = 0; j < centroids[maxInstance].length; j++){

}
```

on your second for loop.

Comment: assuming your double open brackets is a typo

Answer (score 0):

This can go either way, without additional information I can't really tell which one is out of bounds.

### Case 1: centroids.length < maxInstance

In that case you simply can't access `centroids[maxInstance]`, If you define them as

```
instances[10];
centroids[5];
int maxInstance = 5;
```

**Potential solution:** Check the size of instances.length and make sure `centroids.length <= instances.length`

### Case 2: index `j` is out of bounds

Assuming `centroids.length <= instances.length` is true. Then
you need to check whether `instances[maxInstance].length > centroids[maxInstance].length`
Imaging where you define them as

```
new instances[maxInstance][10];
new centroids[maxInstance][5];
```

Then you will get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5` when you try to access

```
j=5; 
centroids[maxInstance][5]
```

**Potential solution:**

```
for(int j = 0; j < centroids[maxInstance].length; j++){ //replace with centroids
```